# BufferedReader unable to read all lines on Google Cloud Storage ReadChannel

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, bufferedreader, nio

I am downloading a Google Cloud Storage object (a GZIP file of size ~400MB, 25 million rows records), with the following code:

```
Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, blobName);
ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
```

The ReadChannel is been gunzip and passed to BufferedReader with following:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new GZIPInputStream(
                                Channels.newInputStream(readChannel)),
                UTF_8));
```

**Problem:**

The BufferedReader will only read until exactly 10110000 lines only (out of 25 millions lines) all the time (tried 10+ times).

**Extra Info:**

1. The google ReadChannel is still endOfStream=false at that point. But the BufferedReader's InputStreamReader has endOfFile=true.
2. I am able to read the full rows (25 millions) from the exact same ReadChannel by using the following:

```
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(500 * 1024 * 1024);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
byte[] gzipFileBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new GZIPInputStream(
                                new ByteArrayInputStream(gzipFileBytes)),
                UTF_8));
```

Really appreciate your helps.

Comment: Is it possible you're exceeding some request timeout - What are you doing with this reader and how long does it take?